# how to convert a string of json into a table format in csv using python code or libraries?

Tags: python, json, csv

MY json which i am using :

```
            {
       "lastMonth":{
     "aotalCost":4120.6241,
     "cpu_avg_partition":{
     "10":{
        "count":1,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":10
     },
     "100":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":100
     },
     "5":{
        "count":16,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":5
     },
     "50":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":50
     },
     "90":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":90
     }
  },
  "providers":{
     "azure":{
        "cost":1844.134
     },
     "aws":{
        "cost":2276.4901
     }
  },
  "period":"lastMonth",
  "resourceTypes":{
     "db":{
        "cost":842.8003
     },
     "bucket":{
        "cost":362.2997
     },
     "server":{
        "cost":976.9376
     },
     "volume":{
        "cost":349.5705
     },
     "instance":{
        "cost":868.4003
     },
     "others":{
        "cost":199.1993
     },
     "null":{
        "cost":521.4163
     }
  },
  "accounts":{
     "188f6226-59d8-4a7c-9fdb-f32f4f0885ff":{
        "cost":19.3469
     },
     "19d2b0d2-d947-4e81-96aa-3b7f9583178a":{
        "cost":543.6707
     },
     "c658a818-b96e-48b4-8a2e-c77404c58af6":{
        "cost":1281.1164
     },
     "628455167342":{
        "cost":2276.4901
     }
  },
  "running_hours_partition":{
     "60":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":60
     },
     "80":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":80
     },
     "20":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":20
     },
     "100":{
        "count":5,
        "cost":1008.16,
        "value":100
     },
     "40":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":40
     }
  },
  "projects":{
     "813":{
        "cost":4120.6241
     }
    }
   },
 "currency_code":"GBP",
   "idmap":{
    "accounts":{
     "188f6226-59d8-4a7c-9fdb-f32f4f0885ff":"AzureForPM",
     "19d2b0d2-d947-4e81-96aa-3b7f9583178a":"AzureForPM",
     "c658a818-b96e-48b4-8a2e-c77404c58af6":"AzureForPM",
     "628455167342":"628455167342"
    },
  "projects":{
     "813":"ACP PM Work"
  }
  },
 "currentMonth":{
  "totalCost":1769.9801,
  "cpu_avg_partition":{
     "10":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":10
     },
     "100":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":100
     },
     "5":{
        "count":10,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":5
     },
     "50":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":50
     },
     "90":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":90
     }
     },
    "providers":{
     "azure":{
        "cost":756.614
     },
     "aws":{
        "cost":1013.3661
     }
  },
  "period":"currentMonth",
  "resourceTypes":{
     "db":{
        "cost":376.3396
     },
     "bucket":{
        "cost":151.4477
     },
     "server":{
        "cost":389.8187
     },
     "volume":{
        "cost":152.1401
     },
     "instance":{
        "cost":369.6178
     },
     "others":{
        "cost":91.6273
     },
     "null":{
        "cost":238.9888
     }
  },
  "accounts":{
     "188f6226-59d8-4a7c-9fdb-f32f4f0885ff":{
        "cost":11.8057
     },
     "19d2b0d2-d947-4e81-96aa-3b7f9583178a":{
        "cost":224.0437
     },
     "c658a818-b96e-48b4-8a2e-c77404c58af6":{
        "cost":520.7645
     },
     "628455167342":{
        "cost":1013.3661
     }
  },
  "running_hours_partition":{
     "60":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":60
     },
     "80":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":80
     },
     "20":{
        "count":1,
        "cost":3.08,
        "value":20
     },
     "100":{
        "count":5,
        "cost":407.314,
        "value":100
     },
     "40":{
        "count":0,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":40
     }
  },
  "projects":{
     "813":{
        "cost":1769.98
     }
  }
```

My python code is as below which i am trying to get the csv file

```
        import json
       from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


         def loading_file():
    #File path
      file_path =
```

'C:/Python27/robotscripts/Analytics_new/MonthlycostCSV/monthly_costformatter_data.json'

```
  #Loading json file
  json_data = open(file_path)
   data = json.load(json_data)
   return data

   #Storing avaliable keys
  def data_keys(data):
   values = {}
   for i in data["lastMonth"]:
    for k in i.str():
        values[k] = 1

   values = values.values()

   #Excluding nested arrays from keys - hard coded -> IMPROVE
      new_keys = [x for x in values if
 x != 'lastMonth' and
    x != 'cpu_avg_partition']

return new_keys

        #Excluding nested arrays from json dictionary
    def new_data(data, values):
  new_data = []
  for i in range(0, len(data)):
    x = {k:v for (k,v) in data[i].items() if k in values }
    new_data.append(x)
return new_data

  def csv_out(data):
 data.to_csv('out.csv',encoding='utf-8')

    def main():
 data_file = loading_file()
 values = data_keys(data_file)
 table = new_data(data_file, values)
 csv_out(json_normalize(table))

    main()
```

I am getting error with values

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\robotscripts\Analytics_new\MonthlycostC
>       main()   File "C:\Python27\robotscripts\Analytics_new\MonthlycostC
>       values = data_keys(data_file)   File "C:\Python27\robotscripts\Analytics_new\MonthlycostC
>       for k in i.values(): AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'

I also tried other programs like:

```
            import json
             import csv

      f = open('monthly_costformatter_data.json')

      data = json.load(f)
     s=csv.writer(open('m1.csv','w'))

       s.writerow(["aotalCost","cpu_avg_partition","providers"])
       for i in data["lastMonth"]:
     s.writerow([i["aotalCost"],i["cpu_avg_partition"],i["providers"]])
```

ERROR FOR THIS :

> C:\Python27\robotscripts\Analytics_new\MonthlycostCSV>monthlycostcsv4.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\robotscripts\Analytics_new\MonthlycostCSV\monthlycostcsv4.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       s.writerow([i["aotalCost"],i["cpu_avg_partition"],i["providers"]]) TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Is there any other simple coding for this json or any package to convert into csv. i tried many options but unable to get proper output.
only i am able to print the headers and not the values with help of pandas
can anyone who know can answer this questions

Comment: I also tried this :
import json
import csv

with open('monthly_costformatter_data.json') as fi:
    data = json.load(fi)
    #df = pd.DataFrame(data=data["lastMonth"]["aotalCost"],columns=data["lastMonth"]["cpu_avg_partition"])
    #df.to_csv('data_table.csv', index=False)

    employ_data = open('data1.csv', 'w')
    csvwriter = csv.writer(employ_data)

    for emp in data["lastMonth"]:
    
             header = emp.keys()

             csvwriter.writerow(header)

             csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())

employ_data.close()
But getting error with keys again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second solution, the `data["lastMonth"]` is a dictionary, you can directly use keys to find the values, no need to use a `for loop`, like this:

```
import json ,ast
import csv

f = open('monthly_costformatter_data.json')

data = json.load(f)
with open('m1.csv','w') as opfile:
    s=csv.writer(opfile)
    s.writerow(["aotalCost","cpu_avg_partition","providers"])
    lastmonth = data["lastMonth"]
    cpu_avg_partition = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(lastmonth["cpu_avg_partition"]))
    providers =  ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(lastmonth["providers"]))
    write_list = [lastmonth["aotalCost"],cpu_avg_partition,providers]
    s.writerow(write_list)
f.close()
```

Note that `lastmonth["cpu_avg_partition"]` and `lastmonth["providers"]` are also dictionary.

if you want to load other dict, eg: `currentMonth` and `idmap`, you can directly use the loaded json data, like you did for `lastMonth`:

```
currentMonth= data["currentMonth"]
idmap= data["idmap"]
```

**Update:**

with pandas, you can load the json file to a dataframe df, then save the df into csv file like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_json("monthly_costformatter_data.json")
new_df = df.transpose()
column_name = new_df.columns.values
print column_name #print column name here
new_df[['totalCost','cpu_avg_partition']].to_csv('test.csv',index=False) #here you can select specific columns you want like 'totalCost','cpu_avg_partition' to write to csv file.
```

Comment: yea thanks tiny , I am getting the output but its coming as {u'10': {u'count': 1 ... how to make go that 'u' , by decoding or delimiter
and how to add the second dictionares like curent month and idmap

Comment: Is there any package available in python like pandas , dictwriter which can i use for this json as strings to csv .
I am begineer for python so i have already searched google many times and tried many examples but need some guidance from others!

Comment: ,, How to encode this and make rid of u from getting printed 
use dictwriter or something ?

Comment: GREAT !!! It really works it knocked off the U, How you people are able to code like this i too want to can you share some info from where you learnt python and any suggestions for me .
Thanks for you great contribution

Comment: can you explain a little more on pandas i dint get the line 
#  #here you can select which column to write to csv file
How can i add the code to print the columns and headers.

Comment: @goel well, coding, coding, and coding... is the best way for me. And come to contribute the community (stackoverflow) regularly, ask question to seek help from other engineers, and answer question if you can to help each other, you will grow from here definitely. good luck :)

Comment: Good job posting the same question a second time, and not even using the fixed indentation that was done to your first question.

Comment: @Tiny.d for the pandas version  i am getting back the same u inside how to get rid of it . i used the same code which u said earlier but not working for this pandas